Are Dabi second powers more powerful than Todoroki's?
In the anime we havent seen it yet, but later in the manga is revealed,

 Dabi has ice powers just like Todoroki's

Since Dabi's fire is more powerful than Todoroki's  , does this mean his second powers also more powerful than his?

Dabi's Blueflame quirk is very powerful as mentioned in the manga.
But there is nothing much revealed about his second power as it is
revealed quite late in the story.

I dont want to give spoilers but I have to because I have to point out the answer is wrong. Dabi has ice powers, it's later revealed in the manga. https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Phosphor

Oh Yes! I forgot about it! I will change my answer.
